# mixing commonjs module with ES6 module to export two functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs, es6-module-loader

I have this file: commonutils.js

```
import { isBoolean, isNil  } from 'lodash'; // isNil , check undefined or null
import moment from 'moment';

let dateToISO = function (dateString) {
  if (!dateString) {
    return null;
  }
  let p = dateString.split(/\D/g);
  return [p[2], p[1], p[0]].join('-');
}
let ISOtoDate = function (dateString) {
  if ( isNil(dateString) || dateString === '') {
    return  '';
  }
  return moment(dateString).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
}

module.exports.dateToISO = dateToISO;
module.exports.ISOtoDate = ISOtoDate;
```

when I try to import on webstorm , webstorm complete the names to imports when I type:

```
import { dateToISO,  ISOtoDate } from './commonutils';
```

but when i execute, i get this error:

```
./src/utils/validators.js
8:10-19 './commonutils' does not contain an export named 'dateToISO'.
```

what are I'm doing wrong?

update:

importing with this:

```
const { dateToISO,  ISOtoDate } = require('./commonutils');
```

I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'dateToISO' of undefined
> module.exports.dateToISO = dateToISO;
```

Comment: ok, where is `dateToISO` defined?

Comment: i've updated the answer with the full code

Answer (score 0):

You are using a CommonJS module export syntax with an ES6 import. For import, you need to do something like:

```
const { dateToISO,  ISOtoDate } = require('./commonutils');
```

Comment: thanks, i'm getting now TypeError: Cannot set property 'dateToISO' of undefined

Comment: I am confused as to why you are using CommonJS exports. Why not just use ES6 exports for the two functions?

Comment: because I execute directly with $ node another  js file that call that library, node does not support directly , can you modify your answer, just change the imports like require, because apparently you can't mix import and commonjs